# How to add HEADERS in vuejs with api keys using AXIOS, for a GET request to a RESTFULL API

Tags: vue.js, request, axios

[I'm trying to make a get request but it's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wfr8.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the headers globally, you can do something like the following in your main.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

For more information, see:
https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax

```
axios.get(your url here,{
       headers:{
            your headers here
}
})
.then((res)=>{
    //do something
})
.catch((err)=>{
 //do something
})
```